# Change text in div class with text from another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the text in the div class "instock" with the words 'Made by' plus the "companyName" text

```
<div class="productDetails">
<div class="description">
<span class="companyName>The Company Name</span>
</div>
<div class="instock">Handmade to order</div>
<div>
```

I want instock to look like this:

```
<div class="instock">Made by The Company Name</div>
```

I've tried this

```
var companyName = document.getElementsByClassName('companyName');
var companyNameText = companyName.nodeValue;
var instock = document.getElementsByClassName('instock');
var instockAlt = instock.nodeValue;
instockAlt.textContent = 'Made by' + companyNameText;
```

Also as this might not always need to be done (when there is no company name for changing) I think I need to check if the span class is there first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JQuery, you can do the following

```
var companyName = $('.companyName').text();
if(companyName){
  $('.instock').html('Made by ' + companyName);
}
```

Comment: I hope the OP doesn't have more than one companyname/instock group to work with because this will fail.

Comment: It's working fine and I found it easiest to understand. I tried answer by j08691 which works as well but not if I have another span before companyName. I'm only using the companyName span when I need it to do this to the single instock class. Thanks to all for answers.

Comment: @Pete _"but not if I have another span before companyName"_ Well why in the world should anyone assume that you have that when you never mention it and it's not in your example? We have to answer based on the information that you provide -- not infinite possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `"` missing in the `<span>`. The line:

```
var companyName = document.getElementsByClassName('companyName');
```

Returns a `HTMLCollection`. Either change it to:

```
var companyName = document.getElementsByClassName('companyName')[0];
var companyName = document.querySelector('.companyName');
```

If you are using jQuery, please use:

```
var companyName = $('.companyName');
var companyNameText = companyName.text();
var instock = $('.instock');
var instockAlt = instock.text();
instockAlt.text('Made by' + companyNameText);
```

The reason is, `textContent` is not available everywhere, while some browsers use `innerText`. jQuery takes care of browser incompatibilities like this.

Also, the final code is `</div>` not `<div>`.

If the whole code is a section block, then you need to use a contextual way:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.instock').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).prev('.description').find('span').length )
      $(this).text('Made by ' + $(this).prev('.description').find('span').text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="productDetails">
  <div class="description">
    <span class="companyName">The Company Name</span>
  </div>
  <div class="instock">Handmade to order</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you could do:

```
$('.instock').html(function() {
  if ( $(this).prev('.description').find('span').length ) return 'Made by ' + $(this).prev('.description').find('span').html()
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jy6tLnv6/1/)**